# How much of a rocket energy is needed to overcome aerodynamic drag?

Tags: launch, orbit, energy

this question
[How much of a rocket's energy is used to achieve altitude vs horizontal velocity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35858/how-much-of-a-rockets-energy-is-used-to-achieve-altitude-vs-horizontal-velocity/) addresses the energy split of kinetic vs. potential energy to get to space - and to stay there.

We know, that the potential energy is a piece of cake vs. the kinetic energy needed.
However, still rockets are launched from Aircraft. And while this has other advantages (weather independence, flexibility of launch location), I wonder how much energy is saved that would otherwise be needed to overcome aerodynamic drag.

Obviously, this depends on the aerodynamic characteristics of the launch vehicle. I found in literature a CD of 0.5, which should probably fit most rockets.
But then, I am lacking the velocity/altitude profiles.

Can someone provide an approximate relation between
Ekin
Epot
Edrag
?

Best regards,
Hendrik

Comment: We typically talk in terms of delta-v, change in velocity, rather than energy, for launchers. See this post for the delta-v cost due to air drag for a launch to LEO. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49596/6944

Comment: [I've done some crude sims on this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/52281/40257) and in delta-v terms drag loss is about 1-2% of total delta-v expended.

Comment: I've heard "gravity drag" takes 0.5 to 1.5 km/sec of delta-v. Direct aerodynamic drag will be way less, but the cut in thrust in most launch programs near max-Q due to *aerodynamic pressure* will have a gravity drag penalty that perhaps could larger than direct aerodynamic drag.