# Are hydrogen balloons a feasible launch device?

Tags: launch

The idea is to use massive cylindrical balloons to raise the vehicle into the upper atmosphere, then reel in the balloons, burning the hydrogen.

Comment: See this question: [Could it be possible to launch a rocket from a balloon?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/1635/4660)

Comment: Also see [Has anyone proposed a serious space dirigible design?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/6517/49) and [Is the “airship to orbit” mission profile feasible?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/6548/49)